# aws read data from athena error using aws wrangler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-data-wrangler

I am using python3

I am trying to read data from aws athena using awswrangler package.

Below is the code

```
import boto3
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd

df_dynamic=wr.athena.read_sql_query("select * from test",database="tst")
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awswrangler/_config.py", line 361, in wrapper

       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 148, in _ 
   endpoint_for_partition
     raise NoRegionError()
      botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

I am not sure to specify and where in order for sql query to work

Comment: Where are you executing your script? On a local computer or or AWS?

Comment: On Aws ec2 instance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All interactions with the AWS APIs (including via SDK, like `boto3`) require credentials, you can find more info on how `boto3` manages credentials [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html).

Since you're running this on an EC2 instance, best practices recommend to manage credentials via Instance Profile. Assuming that you have already assigned an IAM Role to the EC2 instance, all you need to do is to specify a region for your code. You can find info on how to assign an IAM Role to your EC2 on the official [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

AWS Data Wrangler relies on `boto3` and allows to specify a region like so:

```py
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name="us-east-2")
```

Source: [AWS Data Wrangler - Sessions](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/blob/master/tutorials/002%20-%20Sessions.ipynb)

You can either hardcode the region like in the example above or you can retrieve the region in which the EC2 is deployed using the [instance metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html).

The following endpoint:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
```

Will return a json that contains, among other info, the region of the EC2:

```json
{
  "privateIp" : "172.31.2.15",
  "instanceId" : "i-12341ee8",
  "billingProducts" : null,
  "instanceType" : "t2.small",
  "accountId" : "1234567890",
  "pendingTime" : "2015-11-03T03:09:54Z",
  "imageId" : "ami-383c1956",
  "kernelId" : null,
  "ramdiskId" : null,
  "architecture" : "x86_64",
  "region" : "ap-northeast-1", # <- region
  "version" : "2010-08-31",
  "availabilityZone" : "ap-northeast-1c",
  "devpayProductCodes" : null
}
```

You can easily implement this request in Python or by other means if needed.

Comment: Thanks Andre , This worked 
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name="us-east-2")
Mean my region was different

Comment: Any idea how to install awswrangler library in pycharm. I know it should be posted separately I was just thinking if you have any answer handy